# How to calculate oxidation number for silver hexafluorophosphate (AgPF6)?

Tags: oxidation-state, structural-formula

I'm doing some exercise of assigning oxidation numbers and I am stuck with this compound:

$$\ce{AgPF6}$$

According to the guidelines fluorine is always -1. But how do I know how to split the +6 among the other to elements?

Comment: Consider it is a ionic compound, similar to LiPF6, the basis of electrolyte of lithium accumulators. And you must have knowledge about usual ONs of Ag and P.

Comment: Review the guide [How to ask](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Asking FAQs](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/asking) to prevent clarification requests, objections,  downvoting or closure.

Comment: Rules are not enough. There is needed to know at least basics of chemistry of involved elements. Otherwise, rules can lead to formally correct nonsense.

Comment: I just googled that Ag usually has an ON of +1, then it's clear that P has to have +5. I didn't have that information. Thank you for your input.

Comment: It is assumed you know that

Comment: It is probably assumed that you know P before you know Ag, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we ignore the zerovalent forms, then silver has two oxidation states. The more common is +1 while we have the highly oxidizing +2 state which is sometimes used in nuclear reprocessing as an electrochemically generated oxidant.

We know that fluorine can accept one electron to reach a noble gas configeration, so we know that we have +6 changes which need to be shared between the Ag and P atoms. If we treat the substance as purely ionic for the electron counting process. Then

With silver(II) we would need to have P(IV), I am unsure if P(IV) has ever been reported. The common oxidation states for P include P(-III), P(0), P(III) and P(V). So this does not look great as an idea.

With silver(I) we would have five plus charges to deal with, as P(V) is common we can assume that the phosphorus is in the +5 oxidation state while the silver is in the +1 oxidation state.

I think that the latter is by far the most likely to be true.

Comment: There's also Ag(III) and lots of ox. states for P, not only IV, but even if Ag(I) somehow wouldn't oxidise lower P state, then Ag(II) or III certainly would.

Comment: I suspect the question doesn't demand speculation about the oxidation state of P in PF6, but *assumes* that the existence of hexafluorophosphate as a stable ion with a single net negative charge is already known.